# How to add javascript password checker to html form

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below HTML form that I'm using as a password change form. When a user is authenticated, they have an option in their profile to change their password and this is the HTML form presented to the user. I have a separate HTML form that I created for registration and this form has some javascript in it to perform a client side password check to make sure it meets certain complexity requirements. I'd like to use this same functionality on the change password HTML form but I'm having some trouble figuring out how best to accomplish this.

Here's my change_password HTML form.

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
 
{% block content %}
 
<div class="user-profile">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h2>Password Change</h2>
  </div>
 
    <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <p>
            {{ form.old_password.label }}<br>
            {{ form.old_password }}<br>
            {% for error in form.old_password.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.new_password.label }}<br>
            {{ form.new_password(size=32) }}<br>
            {% for error in form.new_password.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>        
        <p>
            {{ form.new_password2.label }}<br>
            {{ form.new_password2(size=32) }}<br>
            {% for error in form.new_password2.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
    </form>
</div>
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
  {% if messages %}
    <ul class=flashes>
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
 
{% endblock %}
```

Here's the form I use for user registration that has the javascript in it for checking the entered password to ensure it meets complexity requirements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
/* Style all input fields */
input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

/* Style the submit button */
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

/* Style the container for inputs */
.container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* The message box is shown when the user clicks on the password field */
#message {
  display:none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#message p {
  padding: 10px 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Add a green text color and a checkmark when the requirements are right */
.valid {
  color: green;
}

.valid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -35px;
  content: "✔";
}

/* Add a red text color and an "x" when the requirements are wrong */
.invalid {
  color: red;
}

.invalid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -35px;
  content: "✖";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="hero is-primary is-fullheight">
        <div class="hero-head">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="container">

                    <div id="navbarMenuHeroA" class="navbar-menu">
                        <div class="navbar-end">
                            <a href="{{ url_for('main.index') }}" class="navbar-item">Home</a>
                            {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
                            <a href="{{ url_for('main.profile') }}" class="navbar-item">Profile</a>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
                            <a href="{{ url_for('main.tables') }}" class="navbar-item">Tables</a>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if not current_user.is_authenticated %}
                            <a href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}" class="navbar-item">Login</a>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
                            <a href="{{ url_for('auth.logout') }}" class="navbar-item">Logout</a>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="hero-body">
            <div class="container has-text-centered">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>



<h3>User Signup Form</h3>
<p>Fill in the information below to create an account. Once you've successfully signed up, you'll be taken to the login prompt.</p>



<div class="container">
  <form method="POST" action="/signup">
    <label for ="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <label for="usrname">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="psw" name="password" placeholder="Password" pattern= "^.*(?=.{12,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#!$%^+=]).*$"title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter and one special character, and be at least 12 or more characters" required>    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

<div id="message">
  <h3>Password must contain the following:</h3>
  <p id="letter" class="invalid">A <b>lowercase</b> letter</p>
  <p id="capital" class="invalid">A <b>capital (uppercase)</b> letter</p>
  <p id="number" class="invalid">A <b>number</b></p>
  <p id="length" class="invalid">Minimum <b>12 characters</b></p>
  <p id="character" class="invalid">Minimum <b>1 special character</b></p>
</div>
                
<script>
var myInput = document.getElementById("psw");
var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
var number = document.getElementById("number");
var length = document.getElementById("length");
var character = document.getElementById("character")

// When the user clicks on the password field, show the message box
myInput.onfocus = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks outside of the password field, hide the message box
myInput.onblur = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
}

// When the user starts to type something inside the password field
myInput.onkeyup = function() {
  // Validate lowercase letters
  var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {  
    letter.classList.remove("invalid");
    letter.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    letter.classList.remove("valid");
    letter.classList.add("invalid");
  }

  // Validate capital letters
  var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {  
    capital.classList.remove("invalid");
    capital.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    capital.classList.remove("valid");
    capital.classList.add("invalid");
  }

  // Validate numbers
  var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(numbers)) {  
    number.classList.remove("invalid");
    number.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    number.classList.remove("valid");
    number.classList.add("invalid");
  }

  // Validate length
  if(myInput.value.length >= 12) {
    length.classList.remove("invalid");
    length.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    length.classList.remove("valid");
    length.classList.add("invalid");
  }

  // Validate character
  var special_character = /[^A-Za-z0-9]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(special_character)) {
    character.classList.remove("invalid");
    character.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    character.classList.remove("valid");
    character.classList.add("invalid");
  }

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to use the same javascript logic on my HTML form. How could I do this? Thanks

Comment: What are all the ` %}`s? It doesn't look like just JavaScript and HTML to me

Answer (score 0):

In the registration you have an entire script section that checks onkeyup for the password bar, as well as several elements to alert the user of what they're missing, simply copy the elements and their id references into the new file, and add an onkeyup event for the password field in the new file, and add all the it statements you have in the registration form, to the new file

Add of now there's no JavaScripts in the first one at all